# how to simulate the performance parameters wand EGT parameter?where can i get the data?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aircraft-performance, egt

I went through a lot of research papers and (kind of) understood the parameters needed for Engine Condition Trend Monitoring. From what I've understood, I need N1speed,N2 speed, Pitch, AOA, Exhaust Gas Temperature, Fuel Flow, Low Pressure Fan Speed, High Pressure Rotor Speed, Engine Pressure Ratio and EGT Margin data.
I'm doing this as a part of my Mtech project and I need some sample data to start working. Also, please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm very new to all this.

Comment: Pitch and angle of attack are completely unrelated to the engines. The other items on your list do look relevant for jet engines.

Comment: Also n1 speed and low pressure fan speed are identical. N2 speed and high pressure rotor speed are identical.